# Writing an array to a text file in perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I am a beginner as you can see.  My script prints out the debug line (1st print) to the console correctly but when it writes to a file (2nd print) everything from the input file is print to the output file in one single line. Example input file

```
20 21 22 23 
30 31
40 41 42
```

the output file is like this:

```
202122233031404142
```

Any help is appreciated

```
my $input_file = "test_input.txt"; #input file name 
my $output_file = "ram_app_out.txt"; #output file name

unless (open (INFILE  , $input_file)){
    die("can't not open input file\n");
} 
unless (open (OUTFILE  , '>>', $output_file)){
    die("can't not open output file\n");
} 

my $in_line = <INFILE>;
my $count = 1;


while($in_line ne ""){
    print ("line number:$count -  $in_line");

    my @array = (split ' ', $in_line);
    my $length = @array;
    print ("array length = $length)");

    for(my $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    print ("element[$i] = @array[$i]\n");
    print (OUTFILE "$array[$i]\n");
    }

    $count++;
    $in_line  = <INFILE>;
}

close $input_file;
close $output_file;
```

Comment: Not the answer but some critiques, you should always use strict and warnings, and use lexical filehandles instead of barewords (`open my $infile, '<', $input_file ... <$infile>`). Iterate through the filehandle in the while loop condition itself because Perl has some special handling there: `while (my $in_line = <$infile>) {`. That will internally check if the result is defined, because you want to iterate until undef, which is different from the empty string.

Comment: You say the output is all concatenated together, but that is not the result I get with your code. I get each number on its own line.

Comment: The warnings in this case are all harmless, but indicate parts that could be improved.

Comment: Trying some telepathy: probably you're viewing your output file with a Windows editor which does not display `\n` Unix string separator correctly?

Comment: #s0me0ne: You are correct - Window editor is the reason I did not see my output file correctly.

Answer (score -2):

Your question is not clear on final output. Is all numbers should be on one line without any *separator* between?

NOTE: I use DATA block as input instead of file, you still need to provide output filename as a parameter. I implemented *crude* reminder if you forget to provide filename.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#my $filename = shift
#       or die "\n\nUsage:\n\t$0 [IN] [OUT]\n\n\tWhere [IN] and [OUT] are files\n";
#
#open DATA, "< $filename"
#       or die "Couldn't open $filename";

my $out = shift
        or die "Provide name for output file";

open OUT, "> $out"
        or die "Couldn't open $out";

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    my @array = split ' ';

    print "Array size: " . (1+$#array) . "\n";

    my $count = 0;

    map { print "element[$count] = $_\n"; 
          print OUT "$_ "; 
          $count++
        } @array; 

    print "\n";
}

print OUT "\n";

close OUT;

__DATA__
20 21 22 23 
30 31
40 41 42
```

Comment: I want each number on one line by itself - It turned out the "\n" did not work with Windows text editor.  Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: If you use Windows (or DOS bases system) you need to use "\r\n" in place of "\n".

https://www.altap.cz/salamander/help/salamand/appendix_txtfiles/